# Singleton & Notification

Tags: cocoa, design-patterns, singleton, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

I have been developing Cocoa Apps for a while and I have a conceptual question regarding the Singleton "pattern" and the use of the `NSNotificationCenter` for communication.

Suppose I have a class that is responsible for storing the credentials of the user in the app. Lets call it `UserAccountController`. Such class exposes public methods to perform login/logout operations and notify *any* interested object that such operations were performed (e.g.: in a tab bar application, I'd like to update all UIViiewControllers when the user logged out).

In my opinion, it wouldn't make sense to have more than one `UserAccountController` object in the application, also, a second `UserAccountController` object could also post notifications to the `NSNotificationCenter`, which may cause troubles to objects registered to receive such notifications.

Given this situation I have two questions:

1. What pattern to use in classes like `UserAccountController`.
2. Any class that uses NSNotifications for information flow in the application should, necessarily, implement the Singleton "pattern"?

By analyzing the Apple's classes I have found that the question 2) makes sense, but I would like to avoid the Singleton "pattern".

Any clues?

Comment: Could you elaborate on item 2, especially what in Apple’s classes hints at this notification => singleton implication? For instance, `NSWindow` and `NSView` post notifications that can be observed by their corresponding controllers and they aren’t singletons.

Comment: @Bavarious, I'm not saying that *every* Apple class that posts notifications is necessarily a Singleton. `UIApplication` for instance is a Singleton, while `NSWindow` and `NSView` aren't. My question is: "Should I know that I can't instantiate more than one `UserAccountController` to avoid "problems" (although I could always test the `object` argument of the `NSNotification`) or should I restrict, by design, that no more than one `UserAccountController` can be instantiated (i.e. turning it into a Singleton)?"

Answer (score 1):

I would store the user credentials in `UserAccountModel` object. That object would hold among other things my current state, i.e. login status. Whenever that status changes, it would post notification to that fact. My `UIApplicationDelegate` would hold a reference to that model. Now, let's say I have a view where the user enters login credentials, `LoginView`. My MVC would be `UserAccountModel` -> `LoginViewController` -> `LoginView`.

Comment: Ok, that's what I'm doing. My AppDelegate holds a `UserAccountController` object and passes it as argument to the other UIViewControllers' constructor. Each UIViewController register itself as an observer of the NSNotifications and access their `UserAccountController` attribute whenever needed. However, the implementation doesn't guarantee that another `UserAccountController` isn't instantiated and, therefore, have the ability to post notifications that may possibly conflict with the ones generated by the UIViewController's  attribute.

Comment: @Eduardo, calling it UserAccountController doesn't help it's your model object. And if your AppDelegate holds a references and expose that thru a property, who else in your code going to create another one?

Comment: I used the 'Controller' sufix because this object *performs* operations such as asynchronous login, logout, etc. I agree that the user credentials could be wrapped in a Model object. Each UIViewController will hold a reference to the `UserAccountController` created by the AppDelegate. As I said, it would not make sense to create another `UserAccountController`, my question is: "If this object post notifications (which are global by nature), should it be, necessarily, a Singleton"?

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be a singleton to post notifications.